# SQL trigger not working in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

so I'm try to create auto increment by using trigger with case
the case works when the parameter insert but the value is not auto increment and stay "001"
here is the code

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `onlinestore`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trigger_sensors`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `trigger_sensors` BEFORE INSERT ON `sensors` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.label IS NULL) THEN
    -- Find max existed label for specified sensor type
    SELECT
      MAX(label) INTO @max_label
    FROM
      sensors
    WHERE
      TYPE = NEW.name;

    IF (@max_label IS NULL) THEN
      SET @label =
        CASE NEW.name
        WHEN 'VIP' THEN 'VIP'
        WHEN 'REGULER' THEN 'R'
        WHEN 'MROOM' THEN 'MR'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
      END;

      -- Set first sensor label
      SET NEW.label = CONCAT(@label, '001');
    ELSE
      -- Set next sensor label
      SET NEW.label = CONCAT(SUBSTR(@max_label, 1, 2), LPAD(SUBSTR(@max_label, 3) + 1, 4, '0'));
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

here is the value in database
[image]

i cannot find where did I does wrong....
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first SELECT query you have a mistake in the WHERE clause. It should be `WHERE NAME = NEW.name;`

Comment: thnks, i wasn't pay attention at that